# Oracle SQL: JOIN by dblink

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I use next SQL-query in Oracle DB:

```
    SELECT T1.*,
           T3.*
    FROM MyTable1 T1
    INNER JOIN MyTable2 T2 ON T2.Id1 = T1.Id
    LEFT JOIN MyTable3@dblink1 T3 ON T3.Id2 = T2.Id
```

This query is very simple and fast (about 1 min, T1 contain about 1 million rows, T3 more then 10 million rows). Now I want to use MyTable4 from dblink1 for filtering selected rows data. For it, I use subquery:

```
        SELECT T1.*,
               T3.*
        FROM MyTable1 T1
        INNER JOIN MyTable2 T2 ON T2.Id1 = T1.Id
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT Sub_T1.*
                        FROM MyTable3@dblink1 Sub_T1
                        INNER JOIN MyTable4@dblink1 Sub_T2 ON Sub_T2.Id3 = Sub_T1.Id
                        WHERE
                                    Sub_T2.MyColumn1 = 'required value') T3 ON T3.Id2 = T2.Id
```

But this query is too slow (more then 20min). If I rewrite this query to:

```
SELECT T1.*,
       T3.*
FROM MyTable1 T1
INNER JOIN MyTable2 T2 ON T2.Id1 = T1.Id
LEFT JOIN  MyTable3@dblink1 T3 ON T3.Id2 = T2.Id
LEFT JOIN MyTable4@dblink1 T4 ON T4.Id3 = T3.Id
WHERE
        T4.MyColumn1 = 'required value'
```

Then my query work fast again, but I donn't like result (I want to see columns of T3 as null, if WHERE return false).
How to improve my second query, for speed up it?

Comment: How many columns are you really planning to use in your result set from T3? Perhaps a view in the database you are linking to (a view composed of MyTable3 joined to MyTable4) or a function is worth trying (cardinalities do not look correct for this).

Comment: I planing to use only 2 columns from T3.

Answer (score 0):

Does phrasing the query with parentheses solve the problem?

```
SELECT T1.*,
       T3.*
FROM MyTable1 T1 INNER JOIN
     MyTable2 T2
     ON T2.Id1 = T1.Id LEFT JOIN 
     (MyTable3@dblink1 T3 JOIN
      MyTable4@dblink1 T4
      ON T4.Id3 = T3.Id AND
         T4.MyColumn1 = 'required value'
     )
     ON T3.Id2 = T2.Id;
```

Or, also:

```
SELECT T1.*,
       T3.*
FROM MyTable1 T1 INNER JOIN
     MyTable2 T2
     ON T2.Id1 = T1.Id LEFT JOIN 
     MyTable3@dblink1 T3
     ON T3.Id2 = T2.Id
        EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MyTable4@dblink1 T4 WHERE T4.Id3 = T3.Id AND T4.MyColumn1 = 'required value'
               )
```

Comment: No, it's uncorrect. I use MyTable4 only for filtering MyTable3 and your query return result without filtering.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still looking for a solution here, try taking your subquery and turning it into a view over on the database to which you are linking via the "dblink1" database link.  Then do the left join against the view, not directly against the underlying tables.

Something like this:

On the database to which you are linking via dblink1 create this view:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW MYVIEW 
AS
SELECT Sub_T1.*
   FROM MyTable3   Sub_T1
   INNER JOIN MyTable4 Sub_T2 
         ON Sub_T2.Id3 = Sub_T1.Id
   WHERE
      Sub_T2.MyColumn1 = 'required value';
```

Then, back over on the other side, rewrite your query as:

```
 SELECT T1.*,
        T3.*
    FROM MyTable1 T1
        INNER JOIN MyTable2 T2 
              ON T2.Id1 = T1.Id
        LEFT JOIN MyView@dblink1 T3 
              ON T3.Id2 = T2.Id;
```